# Terse output format for arrays and hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable, pretty-print

PowerShell normally pretty prints arrays and hashtables

```bsh
> 1, 2, 3
1
2
3

> [ordered]@{a = 1; b = 2 ; c = 3}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
a                              1
b                              2
c                              3
```

That is wonderful but sometimes I would like to have a terse, one-line output that is not "pretty printed" - like in Python:

```py
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

>>> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is that doable in PowerShell (without transforming the array into a string representation)?

Answer (score 2):

```
1,2,3 | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

[1,2,3]


[ordered]@{a = 1; b = 2 ; c = 3} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I asked for ("without transforming the array into a string representation") but this is the closest I could come up with: `format-nicely` from the [assert module](https://github.com/nohwnd/Assert) is doing a pretty good job. There's a bug that the command is not exposed on import so one has to import the module file directly.